# Python extract first element from list and clean strings

Tags: python, string, list

I am parsing txt files (of +100 pages long) and would like to extract the sentence in which the string "public offering price" appears for the first time. Plus, I want to clean the "&nbsp" characters in that sentence.

I run the following code over a series of files (file_list):

```
test1 = [] #create a new list to store my desired output
    for eachfile in file_list:
        with open(eachfile, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                if "public offering price" in line:
                    test1.append(line.replace('&nbsp;','').split('.')[0])
    print(test1)
```

With the above code I successfully clean the `"&nbsp;"` characters and split elements when a "." is present (something that helps for my desired output), but obtain the following output:

```
['public offering price will be between $and $per share', 'toadditional shares of our common stock at the initial public offering price', '(2)an initial public offering price of $per share']
```

The above output gives me all sentences including my desired string, but I only want to keep the first occurrence:

```
['public offering price will be between $and $per share]
```

Any idea of how to obtain such output? It must be easy to implement given the code I run, but couldn't figure out how...

Thank you so much in advance,

EDIT: The output obtained without replacing or splitting('.')[0] is the following:

```
['public offering price will be between $&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;and $&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;per share. We intend to apply to list the common stock on\n', 'to&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;additional shares of our common stock at the initial public offering price.</FONT>\n', '(2)&nbsp;an initial public offering price of $&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;per share, the midpoint of the initial public offering range indicated on the cover of this prospectus. </FONT> <FONT SIZE=2>\n']
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.
Your posted code fails for indentation errors and undefined variables.  You also have superfluous code -- `line2` is unused.

Comment: If your problem is merely getting the first element of a list, then you should work through a tutorial on lists -- and you have a *lot* of unneeded code.  :-)

Comment: Thank you all. To @Prune: the raw txt file contains +100 pages, that is why I could not put the source text. Can I upload a txt file somewhere? I am aware of the superfluous code, the new edit is simplified.

Comment: The keyword is **minimal**.  Simply hard-code a list of a few strings; iterate through that.  If you want to emulate a problem with multiple files, make lists of 3 strings each, and put those into a list.

Answer (score 0):

Take the first element of the list:

```py
first_elem = test1[0]
print(first_elem)
```

EDIT: to get every first desired string of every file:

```py
test2 = [] #create a list to store all lists 
    for eachfile in file_list:
    test1 = [] #create a new list to store my desired output
        with open(eachfile, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                if "public offering price" in line:
                    test1.append(line.replace('&nbsp;','').split('.')[0])
        test2.append(test1)

    for test1 in test2:
        print(test1[0]) #print first element of each nested list
```

Comment: Thank you @s1rsimon. This is exactly what I want but can not be done within the same "test1.append(line.replace('&nbsp;','').split('.')[0])" line of code?

Comment: the 0 index in `test1.append(line.replace('&nbsp;','').split('.')[0]` takes the first element of every line (after the split) that contains the phrase "public offering price" but i've read your text in the other comment and you have 3 lines with "public offering price" so you have a `test1` array with 3 pieces of string that contain your desired phrase. At this point when you get the 0 index element of that array you get the string you want

Comment: but if you are searching for that line and it's the same in all text files except for the numbers why you don't scan lines for `public offering price will be between` instead of just `public offering price`

Comment: Thanks. Some times the string is not "will  be between" but "is bewteen" or "to be between" or many others, what is always constant is the "public offering price" and the ending with "per share.". Your code above works fine when I only include 1 file in my file_list, but I don't know how to introduce it in the loop to have a final output being ['sentence for first txt','sentence for second txt','sentence for third txt' and so on....]

Comment: For that problem you should append every line saved from a file in a list and then append that list to another list that contains all lists of strings from each file. Then get the first element of each nested list and you are good to go.
Look at the edit in my answer for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `break` in your for loop, to skip to the next file.

```
test1 = [] #create a new list to store my desired output
    for eachfile in file_list:
        line2 = ""  # Create var with lines
        with open(eachfile, 'r') as f:
            for line in f:
                line2 = line2 + line
                if "public offering price" in line:
                    test1.append(line.replace('&nbsp;','').split('.')[0])
                    break
    print(test1)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `break` to exit from your loop:

```
test1 = [] #create a new list to store my desired output

for eachfile in file_list:
    line2 = ""  # Create var with lines
    with open(eachfile, 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line2 = line2 + line
            if "public offering price" in line:
                test1.append(line.replace('&nbsp;','').split('.')[0])
                break

print(test1)
```

Comment: Thank you @rusu_ro1. The problem is not really exiting from the loop, but keeping the first element of the output in "test1.append(line.replace('&nbsp;','').split('.')[0])"

Comment: from each file ?

Comment: can you put the entire line ? maybe your split is the problem

Comment: Yes, exactly. So, I would like a list of "public offering price will be between $and $per share" for each file. This example does not contain any $value, but many file would read like: "public offering price will be between $12 and $15 per share", and I am ultimately interested in the numbers

Comment: than use only one break ?

Comment: Thank you, the entire line goes like this: ['public offering price will be between $&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;and $&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;per share. We intend to apply to list the common stock on\n', 'to&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;additional shares of our common stock at the initial public offering price.</FONT>\n', '(2)&nbsp;an initial public offering price of $&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;per share, the midpoint of the initial public offering range indicated on the cover of this prospectus.  </FONT> <FONT SIZE=2>\n']

Comment: so did you got what you expect ?